# FQL: How can I Return / Filter all my app users by age, sex etc

Tags: facebook, filter, facebook-fql

Can I return a list of all my Facebook app users who are male for example, so far I have:

```
SELECT name FROM user WHERE sex= "male" AND uid IN ( SELECT uid FROM user WHERE is_app_user=1 )
```

..but Facebook wont allow this, as 'is_app_user' is not indexable (surely it should be). I have all permissions and all that, I also have my own database containing a list of the app user id's.

Answer (score 0):

When the user logs in, you should store that information server side for quick access.  The `is_app_user` field only related to the current logged in user, so you cannot query that via the api.

I would suggest that when a user authenticates your app, you should store some information you might need about them on your server.  Just remember to implement the de-authorization callback so you can remove the data when the user removes authorization for your app.

Comment: problem there is if the user changes some of their details on Facebook (such as their location) it will also need to be updated on my database

Comment: You didn't specify that as a constraint on your original question.  For changes, you should use the subscription model in the "Real Time Updates API" from Facebook.